# Julia - Dual command line

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way to have one Julia instance running, but having fx every input on the left and every output on the left? This is because sometimes it gets more difficult to keep track of what I've done in the REPL, but I do need the array to be printed after fx some calculation

```
julia> a = [1,2,3,4,5]                  |    5-element Array{Int64,1}:
                                        |     1
                                        |     2
                                        |     3
                                        |     4
                                        |     5
```

Comment: I rather like this idea, but perhaps you should move to using IJulia at that point?

Comment: I see, do you know if I can "do stuff" in the terminal, and have the output appear in the notebook?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm pretty sure you can't.  (I can think of a few more or less hacky ways to make it work with a lot of effort)

Comment: I don't think this can be solved (quickly) on the "julia interpreter-compiler" side. You should consider alternatives to the "what are other workflows and IDEs to work with julia?". My personal recommendations are [neoterm](https://github.com/kassio/neoterm), [ESS](https://ess.r-project.org/) and [Juno/Atom](https://github.com/JunoLab/uber-juno/blob/master/setup.md). They all take the "I have a lot of code, but I want to see what I'm dealing with at certain stages by sending blocks of text/code to a running process" approach

Comment: Maybe you can add this as a feature request in [OhMyREPL.jl](https://github.com/KristofferC/OhMyREPL.jl)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, atom/juno is the way to get this functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can run a file line-by-line in Atom using the Juno IDE and print the output to the REPL. This will do what you would like.